# Naturality of $n$-truncation

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I'm looking at the HoTT book and struggling to understand why the homotopy $\text{nat}_n^f : \| f \|_n \circ |-|_n \sim |-|_n \circ f$ is not judgemental (defined in equation 4.3.4). By truncation induction, we define $\| f \|_n$ from $|-|_n \circ f$ using Theorem 7.3.2, so by eta-reduction, $\| f \|_n \circ |-|_n \equiv |-|_n \circ f : A \to \| B \|_n$.

Can someone explain to me why we don't take this judgementally? Is there still some doubt that computational rules for point-constructors can be taken to be judgemental?

Comment: Please fix the title of your question.

Comment: Thought the text box was a captcha, huh?

Comment: Apologies for this. I had to stop writing this question halfway through and while Firefox restored the textbox content, the title must've been missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that under the book's rules that point-constructors have judgmental computation laws, for any $a$ we have $\Vert f\Vert_n(|a|_n) \equiv |f(a)|_n$.  I guess with judgmental eta-conversion that implies the functions are also judgmentally equal.